# Rouché's theorem about the equation $\log(z + 3) + z = 0$ in $D_{1/4}(0)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been asked to evaluate the number of zeros in $D_{1/4}(0)$ of the equation $$\log(z + 3) + z = 0$$

If I define $f(z) := \log(z + 3) + z$ the problem is switched to find the zeros of $f$. I'm quite new to complex analysis and I would like to use Rouché's theorem but shouldn't $f$ be holomorphic in an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ s.t. the closure of $D_{1/4}(0)$ is a subset of $\Omega$?
How can $f$ be holomorphic if $\log(z+3)$ is not well defined in $D_{1/4}(0)$ ?

I apologize if I had said something bad, and if so, please tell me where I'm wrong.

Comment: what's D[1/4] (0)?

Comment: the open disk centered in the origin with radius 1/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the function $f(z)=\log(z+3)$.

The minimum modulus of $\log(z+3)$ in $\displaystyle D_{\frac{1}{4}}(0)$ is $\displaystyle \log\left(\frac{11}{4}\right)$, at $z=\displaystyle -\frac{1}{4}$ so $f(z)$ definitely doesn't have a root in the disc.

The maximum modulus of $g(z)=z$ on that ssame disc is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}$, so by Rouche's Theorem, since we have guaranteed $|f(z)|>|g(z)|$ everywhere in the disc (and on the boundary), $f(z)+g(z)$ does not have a root in the disc.

Comment: thank you. But about $log(z+3)$, where is it holomorphic?

Comment: it depends where you define the branch cut! for this problem, you could define it to be holomorphic everywhere except $\text{Im}(z)=0, \text{Re}(z) \leq -3$, or in other words just the portion of the x axis which is less than -3.